# The function defining path-connectedness

Tags: general-topology, continuity

To consider two points to be path connected in some topological space, there has to be a continuous function from the interval $[0, 1]$ to the path in the topological space.

Using the definition of continuity where the pre-image of any open set in the range has to be an open set in the domain begs some questions:

1. What topology is used for the path in the range?
   My guess would be the topology inherited from the overall topology.
2. What topology is used for the domain $[0, 1]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is normally defined to be continuous from $[0,1]$ to the space that contains the two points. If you look at the function from $[0,1]$ to its range, then this is equivalent to being continuous where the topology for the range is the subspace topology.

On $[0,1]$ the topology is that induced as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. This is, open sets are arbitrary unions of sets of the form $(a,b)\cap [0,1]$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$.

Comment: There is no unique topology for $\mathbb{R}$, therefore you have to specify what topology you have provided $\mathbb{R}$ with in order to talk about this topology being induced on [0, 1]. Or do you mean that [0, 1] always inherits the euclidian topology from $\mathbb{R}$, regardless of what topology you might have established on the output topological space?

Comment: @StijnBoshoven It is the topology in which the open sets are arbitrary unions of sets of the form $(a,b)$, for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$. Yes, for the definition of path-connected, paths are assumed to be continuous for this specific pair of topologies.

Comment: Oh thanks! The course that I'm doing on topology focusses on very strange topologies so it wasn't clear to me that the definition of path-connectedness relies entirely on the euclidean/standard topologies. I can't upvote you cuz I have very little rep. but thanks a lot!

Comment: @StijnBoshoven Ah, who cares about internet points. More important is that you learned what you didn't know.

Comment: @StijnBoshoven If cardinalRed answered your question, consider clicking the check mark below the upvote/downvote buttons — this will remove your question from the “unanswered” pool

Comment: What stil doesn't sit right with me is that it now seems that there is no definition for path connectedness for spaces that use any topology other than the standard topology. Is this correct?

Comment: When posting this question I was thinking there would be some way to induce the topology of the topological space down to the path through it and also to the interval [0, 1] so that you get a coherent story for any topology established in the topological space. Is this not correct? Could it be that the topology for [0, 1] is the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}$ with a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ the same as the topology of the path induced by the overall topology of the topological space that the path is in?

Comment: This seems logical and would also manifest in the way that you described in the case of the euclidian topology on the overall topological space.

Comment: @StijnBoshoven Note that we didn't ask anything about the topology of the target space. We just use the topology that it has. So, paths are continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to X$. Only $[0,1]$ has a fixed topology. The space $X$ is whichever space is being studied. Path-connectivity is interested in studying maps from this particular domain as a generalization of curves. Other concepts in topology would look at other types of maps. For example, connectivity looks at maps $f:X\to \{0,1\}$ where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology.

Comment: Oh you're right, the target space need not have a fixed topology for [0,1 ] to have one. This is then generalizable to any topology on the target space. Great!

Answer (score 0):

The topology on $[0,1]$ can be seen in at least three equivalent ways:

1. The subspace topology as a subset of $\Bbb R$ in the Euclidean topology (induced by the metric $(x,y) \to |x-y|$, or by the order topology: all unions of open intervals $(a,b)$). So an Euclidean open set intersected with $[0,1]$.
2. As a metric space in its own right, the restricted metric $(x,y) \to |x-y|$, so open sets are unions of metric balls, etc.
3. As an ordered space in its own right: with as a base all sets of the form $[0,a), 0<a\le 1$, $(a,1], 0\le a < 1$ and $(a,b)$, $a,b \in [0,1]$.

This all yields the same topology which makes $[0,1]$ connected and compact (connectedness being the most important here, as then path-connectedness becomes a stronger version of connectedness..)

For path-connectedness we just need a continuous function from $[0,1]$ (in this topology) to $X$, the space we are considering for path-connectedness (which presumably already has a topolgoy of its own). We can restrict the co-domain to $f[[0,1]]$ but for continuity that doesn't matter, when $f[[0,1]]$ gets the subspace topology from $X$ (as is standard).